# minted: Error when using customized fontfamily

Tags: xetex, minted

I want to use minted to display code in Latex in a customized font, e.g. Monaco. Here is my code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{minted}
\newfontfamily\monaco{Monaco}
\setminted[matlab]{fontfamily=\monaco}
\begin{document}
  \begin{minted}{matlab}
    clear all;
    syms k t f har;
    left = -10; right = 10; down = -0.5; up = 1.5;
    f = sinc(k/2)/2 * exp(1j*k*pi*t/2)
  \end{minted}
\end{document}
```

However, when I build the code in vscode, the intepreter get stuck and takes 90% of the CPU. Meanwhile, it gives me the following error.

> Missing \endcsname inserted.

If I do not use `\newfontfamily` command then I can only use the pre-defined fontfamily. How can I use a customized font in minted?

Comment: Do you only want to use that font for Matlab code or all monospaced text in the document (then `\setmonofont` would be easiest). If only for that, you should try using the NFSS name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fontfamily should not be a command calling a font but a nfss-family name. You can declare such a familyname with the NFSSFamily key (I used Arial as I don't have your font):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{minted}
\newfontfamily\monaco{Arial}[NFSSFamily=ArialFamily]
\setminted[matlab]{fontfamily=ArialFamily}
\begin{document}
  \begin{minted}{matlab}
    clear all;
    syms k t f har;
    left = -10; right = 10; down = -0.5; up = 1.5;
    f = sinc(k/2)/2 * exp(1j*k*pi*t/2)
  \end{minted}
\end{document}
```